# Sorting Data from External JS File Numerically by Price

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a ecommerce website and the data is being pulled from what will be an external JS file containing an array of all of the products.

I currently have a "sort" button and want to sort the books by their price which is a numerical value. Depending on the category that is selected, the books on the page should sort from high to low and low to high when the button is clicked.

I have done this in using SQL but never this way, any help is appreciated!

```
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-0">
  <div class="medium-3 cell">
    <div class="SubjectContainer">
      <div class="float-left">
        <div class="filterTitle" style="padding-left: 5px">Choose a subject</div>
        <div class="filterctn">
          <div class="optionctn">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="accounting" id="accounting">
            <label class="filterlabel" for="accounting">Accounting</label>
          </div>
          <div class="optionctn">
            <input type="checkbox" name="subject" value="agriculture" id="agriculture">
            <label class="filterlabel" for="business">Agriculture</label>
          </div>                 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filterTitle">Sort by Price<br>
  <small style="padding-top: 10px">(highest to lowest)</small> </div>
  <button class="sortBtn" onclick="sorted()">Sort</button>
</div>
```

***Data***

```
<script>
  AllSubjects([{
    "journalfilter": "accounting",
    "journalorder": "1",
    "journaltitle": "Accounting I",
    "journalprice": "22",
  },
  {
    "journalfilter": "accounting",
    "journalorder": "2",
    "journaltitle": "Accounting II",
    "journalprice": "12",
  },
  {
    "journalfilter": "agriculture",
    "journalorder": "3",
    "journaltitle": "Agriculture I",
    "journalprice": "40",
  },
  {
    "journalfilter": "agriculture",
    "journalorder": "4",
    "journaltitle": "Agriculture II",
    "journalprice": "25",
  },
  {
    "journalfilter": "agriculture",
    "journalorder": "5",
    "journaltitle": "Agriculture III",
    "journalprice": "16",
  },
  ]);

</script>
```

Comment: in your filter you have multiple kind of subjects accounting, business etc, which is the key from the AllSubjects data is used for that one ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the code. Thanks for taking the time to help out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```js
/* Ascending */
yourArray.sort((a, b) => {
    return parseInt(a.journalprice) - parseInt(b.journalprice);
});
```

```js
/* Descending */
yourArray.sort((a, b) => {
    return parseInt(b.journalprice) - parseInt(a.journalprice);
});
```

I would recommend, that you store the prices as numbers, more specifically integers (so store 1$ as 100), but not as string.

Comment: If all of the other values are stored as strings in the array, how would I store the prices as integers while still keeping the decimal point?

Comment: @bicycle4431 You do not keep the decimal point. When showing on the page, you convert your integer to a "human readable" price, like 123 as integer becomes '$ 1.23'. Adjust for whatever currency you are using.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried your answer and edited the question to include my attempt at the bottom of making it a function. However, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: AllSubjects.sort is not a function at myFunction (test.html:1332) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

Comment: @bicycle4431 You get this error because `AllSubjects` is not an array, it looks like a method. There seems to be bits missing to fully understand your code. The array I assumed is being passed to that `AllSubjects` method. Either paste the rest of the code explaining `AllSubjects` or remove it and rewrite it as an array.

Comment: @bicycle4431 No worries. Is that array we are talking about static? If so, simply do `const myArray = [{ ... }];` instead of `AllSubjects([{ ... }]);`. Carefully mind the different types of brackets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205878/discussion-between-bicycle4431-and-ffritz).

Comment: @bicycle4431 Let's do the chat.